# How to pass props to React component using React Router after state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a web app and it contains a dropdown list with various `scores`. Each `score` looks like this:

```javascript
<NavDropdown.Item 
  key = {i}
  id = {score["scoreId"]}
  onClick = {(e) => {
    setScore(score)
    window.location.href = '/home/score'
    // do something to go to the score page
  }}
>
  {score["scoreName"]}
</NavDropdown.Item>
```

When clicking on a `score`, I first use `setScore()` to set the `score` state to the currently selected score, then redirect to `/home/score`

```javascript
<Routes>
  <Route path="/score" element={<ScoreHome score={score}/>} />
</Routes>
```

Problem:
I need to pass the newly set `score` prop to the `<ScoreHome />` component, but `useState()` is asynchronous so `props.score` would be undefined on the new page.

`useState` doesn't have callback functions and I tried to use `useEffect` for something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.location.href = '/home/score'
},[score])
```

But this creates an infinite loop for me (the browser keeps jumping to or refreshing `/home/score`)

What's the best way to handle this? Thanks!

Comment: You should use a Context: https://en.reactjs.org/docs/context.html or, in case you might want to invoke the same url with a parameter, use query parameters instead.

Comment: For passing data from one route to another you can use "useNavigate" hook that react-router-dom provides. In this you can redirect you page as well as pass the state as the 2nd argument. See [this](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate) for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With React-Router, you can pass a state with your navigation call, like so:

```
...
  const navigate = useNavigate();
...
<NavDropdown.Item 
  key = {i}
  id = {score["scoreId"]}
  onClick = {(e) => {
    navigate('/home/score', { state: {score} });
  }}
>
  {score["scoreName"]}
</NavDropdown.Item>
```

Then in **ScoreHome.js**

```
const {state} = useLocation();

// state.score <= your selected score
```

[See docs for more](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This does pass the score state to `ScoreHome` but it still doesn't change `score` on click. i.e. `state.score` is still undefined in `ScoreHome`.

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question slightly. I thought you wanted to pass the new score to `ScoreHome` and that should do it if you extract the new score in the onClick hander and send it to `ScoreHome`

Comment: Your answer fixed part of my problem and I fixed the other half. For some reason after using `useNavigate()` and `useLocation()` the `useEffect()` no longer causes infinite loops, so I was able to use `score` as a dependency and do the page navigation in `useEffect()`. Still, thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

With the help from @Moath, I was able to navigate to `ScoreHome.js` with the updated score in `useEffect()` without causing infinite loops. Here's what I did:

```javascript
const navigate = useNavigate();

useEffect(() => {
  if (score["scoreId"] !== undefined) {
    navigate('/home/score',{state:{score, 'overview': false}})
  }
},[score])
```

And in ScoreHome.js:

```javascript
const location = useLocation()
// got score here
var score = location.state.score
```